# The import oracle.jdbc cannot be resolved

Tags: java, oracle

I am currently working on a project where we have to connect to a database and through Java insert values into our database. Our professor gave us code in order to help us see how to carry that out. I am new to Java and have very little experience in it but I have been watching videos and researching online. My problem  is the following: I am working in eclipse and have created a class called `_DataGenerator_` all the code that is there is from my professor.

```
import java.sql.*;

import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;

public class TestDataGenerator {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        String database = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@131.130.122.4:1521:lab";
        String user = "a+MatrNr";
        String pass = "Oracle-Passwort";

        // establish connection to database 
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(database, user, pass);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        // insert a single dataset into the database
        try {
            String insertSql = "INSERT INTO person VALUES ('012345678902', 'Erich', 'Schiküta', 'Wien', 1010, 'Rathausstrasse 19', '12-FEB-2000', 'Wien')";
            stmt.executeUpdate(insertSql);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Fehler beim Einfuegen des Datensatzes: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        // check number of datasets in person table
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM person");
        if (rs.next()) {
            int count = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("Number of datasets: " + count);
        }

        // clean up connections
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The only error I get when trying to run the code is from
`import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;`
When I put my cursor over the error symbol it says

> the import oracle.jdbc cannot be resolved

When I try to run the code the only message I get back is
the statement in Red `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`
I don't know what the problem is. I don't know if it helps to know that I have created my database in oracle SQL developer.

Comment: You need to put the Oracle JDBC driver jar into the class path. Read about using external libraries.

Comment: Cool that there is over 7k who have looked at this problem but for those viewing I am poor stack overflow user and I need some points so that I can place bounties on my other questions. If you can please upvote the question and answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In eclipse, right click your project->`Build Path`->`Config Build Path`->find the `Libraries` tab and press the `Add External Jars`, locate your `oracle jdbc driver` in your hard driver and select it. Make sure it appears in the jars list, and then press `apply and close`.

you can find the oracle jdbc driver in the offical website:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html.

After that this issue should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Well,the jdbc lib  of official oracle is not in maven repo,you should download it from Oracle Website and maven install your path.And if you use maven build your project,you can do this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=E:/app/Administrator/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then add to dependency like :

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It is quite unlikely that the OP is using maven.

Comment: I like this solution, so elegant, so easy to understand and nudges future developers towards software engineering instead of cargo cult.